# Which commercial company was the earliest adopter of Linux?

Tags: history

I tried reading some articles and even watched [Revolution OS](http://www.revolution-os.com), but was unable to come to a conclusion. Thought this would be a better place to get the answer.

From my gathered information: It is either IBM or Dell or something else.

> Which commercial company was the earliest to adopt/port to Linux?

PS: If I am in the wrong community of StackExchange, then please comment the correct section.

Comment: The closest suitable site might be https://unix.stackexchange.com/, but looking at their allowed questions, it would be border line.

Answer (score 1):

It might be impossible to say conclusively which was the first.

However one good way to learn about early business adopters of Linux would be to read about companies like Redhat and SUSE, which were not only using Linux very early on, but actually had it at the core of their business.

Both companies were releasing their Linux distributions for sale in 1994 - just 3 years after Linus announced the creation of Linux (and several years before IBM became seriously involved with Linux development).

Comment: I got the information as Oracle. Can you attest to it?